# How do I set a new WebApplication to deploy at a specific time (i.e. 03:00)?

Tags: deployment, web-application

Is there a way to set this up so that the new application deploys at a specific time of the day? Maybe even on a specific day of the week?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: +1 to SPDoctor's comment - creating a Web app is an up front, infrastructure task as opposed to something that should be done regularly. It would be good to understand your business requirement a little more.

Answer (score 5):

Can write a PowerShell script and link it with the Task Scheduler (where it is possible for you to schedule the script running time)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom timer job for it.

If you want to deploy content from one web application to another(in same or different farm), Use Content Deployment job